# Map for each value of an array in a Spark Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a json data set in the following format, one entry per line.

```
 { "sales_person_name" : "John", "products" : ["apple", "mango", "guava"]}
 { "sales_person_name" : "Tom", "products" : ["mango", "orange"]}
 { "sales_person_name" : "John", "products" : ["apple", "banana"]}
 { "sales_person_name" : "Steve", "products" : ["apple", "mango"]}
 { "sales_person_name" : "Tom", "products" : ["mango", "guava"]}
```

I want to know who sold maximum mangoes and so on.
Hence I want to load the file to dataframe and emit a (key, value) pair of (product, name) for each value of product in the array for each transaction.

```
var df = spark.read.json("s3n://sales-data.json")
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- sales_person_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)

var nameProductsMap = df.select("sales_person_name",  "products").show()
+-----------------+--------------------+
|sales_person_name|   products         |
+-----------------+--------------------+
|             John|[mango, apple,...   |
|              Tom|[mango, orange,...  |
|             John|[apple, banana...   | 

var resultMap = df.select("products", "sales_person_name")
                  .map(r => (r(1), r(0)))
                  .show()  //This is where I am stuck.
```

I am not able to figure out the right way to explode() the row(0) and have all its values emitted once with row(1) value. Can anyone suggest a way. Thanks!

Expected output:

```
Mango : John(4), Tom(2), Greg(1)... 
Banana: Tom(5), John(2), ...
```

Comment: I am trying something like : var actorHashtagsMap = df.select("products", "sales_person_name").map(r => {
    r(0).map(x => (x, r(1)))
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The following code should work

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import scala.collection.mutable

val resultMap = df.select(explode($"products"), $"sales_person_name")


def counter(l: TraversableOnce[Any]) = {
  val temp = mutable.Map[Any, Int]()
    for (i <- l) {
      if(temp.contains(i)) temp(i) += 1
      else temp(i) = 1
    }
  temp
}

resultsMap.map(x => (x(0), Array(x(1)))).
           reduceByKey(_ ++ _).
           map { case (x,y) => (x, counter(y).toArray) }
```

The resulting output: `Array((banana,Array((John,1))), (guava,Array((Tom,1), (John,1))), (orange,Array((Tom,1))), (apple,Array((Steve,1), (John,2))), (mango,Array((Tom,2), (Steve,1), (John,1))))`

Comment: Yeh this is an intermediate step. I finally want to reduce it by col product to reach : apple : John(4), Tom(2), Steve(1) ; mango: Steve(3), Tom(1); //

Comment: Updated the answer for the reduce operation.

Comment: Thanks for the code @septa However I am getting the following error. error: value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Any, Array[Any])]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value reduceByKey'?   I am getting this for any kind of map() I am doing on the result set. I am using Spark 2.0. Any clue?

Comment: <console>:157: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: scala.collection.TraversableOnce[Any]
                  map { case (x,y) => (x, counter(y).toArray) }
                                                  ^

Comment: The code above is for Spark 1.6.x. Unfortunately Spark 2.0 has a sightly different API that I'm not familiar with yet. The idea should be the same however.

Answer (score 5):

```
val exploded = df.explode("products", "product") { a: mutable.WrappedArray[String] => a }
val result = exploded.drop("products")
result.show()
```

prints:

```
+-----------------+-------+
|sales_person_name|product|
+-----------------+-------+
|             John|  apple|
|             John|  mango|
|             John|  guava|
|              Tom|  mango|
|              Tom| orange|
|             John|  apple|
|             John| banana|
|            Steve|  apple|
|            Steve|  mango|
|              Tom|  mango|
|              Tom|  guava|
+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar! You made it look easy.  I had to put the import statement for mutable._ and also the explode is on the select() result not df. I got your concept, and it is easy now. Thanks!